# Hi-Link HLK-RM04 running openwrt, is multithreading possible?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, openwrt

We have an Android and iOS app that interacts with a hardware component that has a Hi-Link HLK-RM04 and running openwrt. We want to be able to respond to UDP broadcasts on this device for discovery while still maintaining the ability to communicate the way we normally do via TCP. We are being told by the outsourced team responsible for development of this component that multi-threading isn't possible in this configuration so we can either respond to UDP broadcasts or accept TCP connections, but not both.

I can't find any information why that may be. I've seen examples of pthreads being used in openwrt on a few forums, so if there is a limitation it seems it must be on the board.

Can anyone shed some light here? Is the team mistaken or do we need to find another way of doing discovery using a single-thread solution?

Thanks in advance.

*EDIT*

Here are some specs on the processor and module

http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/hilink/hlk-rm04

https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Wireless/WiFi/RT5350.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenWRT is Linux — there are numerous ways to handle different types of connections in parallel on Linux, even if threads are not available. (For instance, one could `poll()` both TCP and UDP sockets, or even just run two processes to handle both types of connections.)

The hardware has nothing to do with it. I suspect your development team is just trying to shift blame.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll ask the team about this and come back and accept if this works out for us.

Comment: Turns out the limitation stems from two boards working together and were only able to update the other board which does not have an OS, we are looking at other options. However your info seems correct so thanks for the answer.

Comment: It's much more plausible that the issue described might exist on a device with no operating system (i.e, not running OpenWRT, and thus not running Linux). It's still almost certainly *possible* to handle both, but I can certainly see how it might be much more difficult.

Comment: There's nothing preventing you from writing a multi-threaded program for a single core/thread platform and letting the kernel handle the time sharing.  Still, with 2 blocking socket listeners, its likely only 1 thread at a time may unblock and consume CPU at a time anyway.

Comment: @EkriirkE As mentioned in comments, one of the boards involved has no operating system (and hence, no kernel). Implementing threads on bare metal is… certainly possible, but quite difficult.